# django:how the template query two data tables

Tags: python, mysql, django

use **django** :I have 2 same database table need to agree to page displays, don't know how to run it.

django views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from book.models import article, update
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world!")

def article_list(request, id):
    articles = article.objects.get(id = id)
    return render_to_response('article.html', {'article':articles})

def title_list(request, id):
    updates = update.objects.filter(bookid = id)
    return render_to_response('article.html', {'update':'updates'})
```

and the urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from book import views
#, article, update
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^templates/(?P<path>.*)$', 
        'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': '/home/hugo/sobook/book/templates'}),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^b/(\d{1,9})/$', views.article_list, name='article_list'),
    url(r'^b/(\d{1,9})/$', views.title_list, name='title_list'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

and models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #name = models.ManyToManyField(update)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    page_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    img_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    siteid = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    sitename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class update(models.Model):
    siteid = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    bookid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #name = models.ManyToManyField(article)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    page_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and template:article.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <link href="/templates/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <title>{{article.name}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>{{article.name}}</h1>
<ul><li><img src='{{article.img_url}}' width="100px"/></li>
<li>作者：{{article.author}} </li>
<li>简介： {{article.intro}}</li>
<li>入库时间：{{article.time|date:"F j, Y" }}</li>
<li>小说状态：{{article.state}}</li>
<li><a href="{{article.page_url}}" title="{{article.name}}">{{article.page_title}}</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="list">
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>最新章节</th>
  <th>来源</th>
  <th>更新时间:{{ title_list.page_title }}</th>
</tr>
{% for person in title_list %}
<tr>
  <td><a href="{{ person.page_url }}">{{ person.page_title }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ person.sitename }}</td>
  <td>{{ person.time }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When accessing:

> localhost/b/12/

views.py **title_list**

Did not query displayed?All else is normal.

Comment: A URL can't point to two views. That makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is in the views.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from book.models import article, update
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world!")

def article_list(request, id):
    articles = article.objects.get(id = id)
    return render_to_response('article.html', {'article':articles})

def title_list(request, id):
    updates = update.objects.filter(bookid = id)
    # You are passing the string 'updates' along instead of the queryset
    #return render_to_response('article.html', {'update':'updates'})
    return render_to_response('article.html', {'update':updates})
```

Further more your view is expecting a variable called "title_list" however this is not supplied, maybe you meant "updates" instead.

In the template you are referring to title_list as both an update instance and a queryset.
You have `{{ title_list.page_title }}` and `{% for person in title_list %}` it's unlikely this is the actual object you created and is most likely an error.

In URLS you're also giving up two views for the same path. This is simply not possible. Each URL has to point to a view. You can't have multiple views assigned to the same URL.

```
url(r'^b/(\d{1,9})/$', views.article_list, name='article_list'),
url(r'^b/(\d{1,9})/$', views.title_list, name='title_list'),
```

Comment: I need to assign these two views the same URL should do, can you give an example.
I just practice the django some places not familiar with, want to correct me, thank you!

Comment: Please elaborate the question on what you want the view to accomplish? What are the links between `article` and `update`. Why should they share the same URL? Can't you just merge the views into one instead?

Comment: Is like that, I have a novel, this novel has many chapters.The novel, I all aspects of information (such as: author, update time and novel introduction) to create a table: article, a novel of each chapter to build a table: update(Can be changed to other names), I hope in a view shows the information and update the chapters of the novel。